# Dynamically add rows to a custom listView ( each row has multiple Strings )

Tags: java, android, listview

My last app had a custom layout, `listview`, I could add items and those items would appear in the `listview`.
Now, I want to make an app, also with custom layout, `listview`, but every row exist of 3 different Strings, so before my app will give a new row, you have to type in 3 different strings and than he will make a new row. But this doesn't work... Can you help me where I made a mistake? thanks already!

***Main Activity***

```
ListView ListView ;

EditText editTextMerk ;
EditText editTextBeschrijving ;
EditText editTextKm ;

Button voegToe ;

ArrayList<String> merk;
ArrayList<String> beschrijving ;
ArrayList<String> km ;

CustomAdapter adapter ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editTextMerk = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMerk) ;
    editTextBeschrijving = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextBeschrijving) ;
    editTextKm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextKm) ;

    ListView =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.Listview) ;
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this , merk , beschrijving  , km ) ;
    ListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    voegToe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            merk.add(editTextMerk.getText().toString()) ;
            beschrijving.add(editTextBeschrijving.getText().toString()) ;
            km.add(editTextKm.getText().toString()) ;

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}
```

***This is my CustomAdapter Class***

```
LayoutInflater mInflater ;

ArrayList<String> merk;
ArrayList<String> beschrijving ;
ArrayList<String> km ;

public CustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> merk, ArrayList<String> beschrijving, ArrayList<String> km) {

    this.merk = merk;
    this.beschrijving = beschrijving;
    this.km = km;

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) ;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return merk.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return merk.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_row, null) ;

    TextView brand  = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewMerk) ;
    TextView discription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewBeschrijving) ;
    TextView distance = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewKm) ;

    brand.setText(merk.get(position));
    discription.setText(beschrijving.get(position));
    distance.setText(km.get(position));


    return v;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically add items to list view using custom adapter for Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939800/dynamically-add-items-to-list-view-using-custom-adapter-for-android-app)

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. You are not finding `voegToe` in `onCreate()` method. Trying to call `setOnClickListener()` on a null object produces NPE.
2. You are not initializing your lists. Passing them while they are null would produce NPE when `getCount()` called when you try to `setAdapter()` to your ListView.

Therefore, you need to update your Activity as follows:

```
ListView listView;

...

ArrayList<String> merk = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> beschrijving = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> km = new ArrayList<>();

...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editTextMerk = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editTextBeschrijving = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editTextKm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    voegToe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, merk, beschrijving, km);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    voegToe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            merk.add(editTextMerk.getText().toString());
            beschrijving.add(editTextBeschrijving.getText().toString());
            km.add(editTextKm.getText().toString());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```